# Is it correct to say "unbinded"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, verb-forms

Let's say I have two objects that I want to bind together (just in abstract manner - matching abstract object).
Now, let's say I have an object that is not bound to any other object. Can I say that this object is "unbinded"?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use it in connection with Prometheus.

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_Unbound_%28Shelley%29).

Comment: Better hint - Percy Bysshe Shelley.

Comment: Here are some [online dictionaries](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574) you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object that is not *bound* isn't * *unbinded,* it is *unbound.*